# Python code to identify structure of a text file

Tags: python, beginner, csv, file-system, pandas

We have a department in our org that generates a lot of data in flat files, all with different formats. We are now trying to sort this data out and load into a database. As step 1, I am trying to identify the structure(separator, header, fields, datatypes, etc) of the files using a python script. This is my first time doing python programming, also I am programming after a long time. While this code gives me the output I need, how can I make it better?

The code looks at the directory C:\logs and loops through all files in the directory first to identify a separator and header, then if the separator is space it will check if it is a fixed width file. use the information here to identify all fields and their related attributes and prints out a mapping file. It also combines multiple mapping files into one mapping file if possible (this allows the mapping sheet to accommodate format variances across multiple files). I want to be able to use this on Excel files later.

SAMPLE INPUT:

[image: Input]
Example Input in txt format below. However this code is supposed to identify 'any character' delimited or fixed width files. Files can have any number of header lines, etc.

```
Some Title

 Grp  IDS   Date    Time     Weight 
  1  3559  3-10-19  8:45    1159.4
  1  3680  3-10-19  8:40    1861.2
  1  3844  3-10-19  8:36    2039.4
  1  3867  3-10-19  8:38    1861.2
  1  3985  3-10-19  8:40    1729.2
  1  4009  3-10-19  8:46    1883.2
  1  4014  3-10-19  8:36    1920.6
  1  4044  3-10-19  8:41    1689.6
  1  4058  3-10-19  8:39    1764.4
  1  4192  3-10-19  8:43    1775.4
  1  4344  3-10-19  8:43    1449.8
  1  4354  3-10-19  8:49    1555.4
  1  4356  3-10-19  8:31    1091.2
  1  4359  3-10-19  8:43       0.0
  1  4361  3-10-19  8:44    1689.6
  1  4365  3-10-19  8:43    1513.6

  2  3347  3-10-19  8:34    1867.8
  2  3860  3-10-19  8:37    1788.6
  2  3866  3-10-19  8:33    1980.0
  2  4004  3-10-19  8:24    1634.6
  2  4020  3-10-19  8:29    1612.6
  2  4086  3-10-19  8:35    1553.2
  2  4139  3-10-19  8:22    1883.2
  2  4145  3-10-19  8:27    1177.0
  2  4158  3-10-19  8:33       0.0
  2  4186  3-10-19  8:29    1586.2
  2  4193  3-10-19  8:28    1746.8
  2  4202  3-10-19  8:28    1870.0
  2  4215  3-10-19  8:31    1104.4
  2  4348  3-10-19  8:33    1628.0
  2  4369  3-10-19  8:32    1392.6
  2  4374  3-10-19  8:33    1394.8
```

OUTPUT:

[image: Output]

```
# Import Libraries
import os
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from dateutil.parser import parse
import calendar

# Set Variables
path = "C:\Logs"
printableChars = list('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c')
skipSeperator = list('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:.!"#$%&\'()*+@[]\n\r\x0b\x0c')
masterFields=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Target Name','Source Name','Column Position','Column Width','DataType','Size','Format', 'KEY','Default','Comments','Unique', 'ImpactsGrain', 'HasNULLs'])
consolidate= True
debug=False

# Identify if any column is duplicate. It needs to be removed from further analysis
def getDuplicateColumns(df):
    '''
    Get a list of duplicate columns.
    It will iterate over all the columns in dataframe and find the columns whose contents are duplicate.
    :param df: Dataframe object
    :return: List of columns whose contents are duplicates.
    '''
    duplicateColumnNames = set()
    # Iterate over all the columns in dataframe
    for x in range(df.shape[1]):
        # Select column at xth index.
        col = df.iloc[:, x]
        # Iterate over all the columns in DataFrame from (x+1)th index till end
        for y in range(x + 1, df.shape[1]):
            # Select column at yth index.
            otherCol = df.iloc[:, y]
            # Check if two columns at x 7 y index are equal
            if col.equals(otherCol):
                duplicateColumnNames.add(df.columns.values[y])

    return list(duplicateColumnNames)

# Identify how column values are separated within a row.    
def identifySeparator(name):
    if debug: print( "Currently analyzing file : " + name)
    currentFile = open(path +"\\" +name, "r")
    # Create a list of charecters by Line
    characterFrequencies =[]
    for line in currentFile:
        characters = list(line)
        if characters[0] == '\n':
            continue
        characterFrequencies.append(Counter(characters))
    if debug: print(pd.DataFrame(characterFrequencies).head())
    df = pd.DataFrame(characterFrequencies)
    df = df.drop(columns=skipSeperator, errors='ignore') # Remove characters that are generally not used as sperators.
    if debug: print("Potential Seperators")
    # METHOD 1: Try to identify seperator with the understanding it should be present in every row.
    dfDense = df.dropna(axis='columns')
    if debug: print(dfDense.head())
    Candidates = dfDense.columns
    if debug: print("Number of characters present in every row : " + str(len(dfDense.columns)))
    if len(dfDense.columns) == 1:
        Separator = str(dfDense.columns[0])
        if debug: print("Separator identified as : " + Separator + ' using METHOD 1')
    else:
        Separator = '-1'
        if debug: print('Unable to identify seperator using METHOD 1 as 0 or multiple exist!!')
    # METHOD 2: Least Variance: The count of the seperator should be more or less same across rows.
    if debug: print('% of rows missing the charecter')
    if debug: print(df.isna().sum()/ df.isna().count())
    cleanupCandidates=df.dropna(axis='columns', thresh = (df.shape[0] + 1)*.8).fillna(-1)
    if debug: print('Dropping characters not present in 80% of the columns')
    if debug: print(cleanupCandidates.head())
    lowestVariance = 0
    spaceDetectedFlag = False
    Separator2 = ''
    for character in cleanupCandidates.columns:
        if debug: print('**********' + character +' **********')
        x = cleanupCandidates.loc[:,character].var()
        if debug: print('Calculated variance : ' + str(x) )
        if character == ' ':
            spaceDetectedFlag = True
            if debug: print('Potential position based file...')
            continue
        if lowestVariance >= x:
            lowestVariance =x
            Separator2 = character
        if debug: print("Separator identified as : " + Separator2 + ' using METHOD 2')
    if Separator == Separator2:
        commonSep= Separator
    else:
        commonSep = list(set(Candidates).intersection(cleanupCandidates.columns))
        if debug: print('Both methods identify '+ str(commonSep) + 'as one of the separator candidates.')
        maxMode = 0
        modeTable = cleanupCandidates.mode()
        if len(commonSep) != 1:
            print ('Multiple Common Seperator!! Use Max MODE', cleanupCandidates.columns)
            if debug: print(cleanupCandidates.mode())
            for column in modeTable.columns: 
                x = modeTable.loc[0,column]
                print (column,'\'s Mode: ', x)
                if x > maxMode:
                    commonSep = column
                    maxMode = x
                if debug: print('Resolved ambiguity by Max Mode Method to: ', commonSep)

    # Identify if header rows need to be skipped
    firstRow = cleanupCandidates[commonSep].idxmax()
    if debug: print('The Header is expected to be in row: ',firstRow)
    return commonSep[0], firstRow

    #candidates = []
    #candidates.append(Counter(characters))


def identifyFixedWidth(name):
    numberLines = 0
    totalCharecters = 0
    maxLength = 0
    for line in open(path +"\\" +name, "r"):
        numberLines +=1
        totalCharecters += len(line)
        if len(line) <= 2: numberLines -=1
        if maxLength < len(line): maxLength = len(line)
    avgChars =totalCharecters/numberLines
    if debug: print('Sample file has '+ str(numberLines) + ' lines. There are an average '+ str(avgChars) +' charecters pe line.')
    counter = 0
    for line in open(path +"\\" +name, "r"):
        if debug: print(str(counter) + ' has ' + str(len(line)) + ' chars')
        if len(line)<= avgChars*.9 or len(line)>=avgChars*1.1:
            if debug: print('Line '+ str(counter) +': Maybe part of header and needs to be skipped')
            counter+=1
        else:
            if debug: print('Header found at column :', counter)
            break
    # Figure out Column Start and stop positions
    rowCounter = -1
    colPos = []
    for line in open(path +"\\" +name, "r"):
        rowCounter+=1 
        if rowCounter < counter: continue
        blanks=[m.start() for m in re.finditer(' ', line)]
        if len(blanks)>2:
            colPos.append([m.start() for m in re.finditer(' ', line)])
            if rowCounter<=5:
                if debug: print(colPos[-1])
    # Intersection
    Common = list(set.intersection(*map(set, colPos)))
    if debug: print('Potential field separator positions: ',Common)
    # Remove sequential values
    newCommon = []
    for x in Common:
        if ((x-1) not in Common):newCommon.append(x)
    newCommon.append(maxLength)
    if debug: print('Field separator positions identified as :',newCommon)
    #Calculate Width
    width=[]
    range = len(newCommon)
    i=0
    for x in newCommon[0:range-1]:
        width.append(newCommon[i+1]-newCommon[i])
        i+=1
    if debug: print('Column Lengths:', width)    
    return counter,width

# Parse File and collect Field Information
def identifyFields(name,separator, HeaderPos, width):
    if debug: print( "Currently analyzing column structure for file : " + name)
    currentFile = path +"\\" +name
    if separator !='FWF':
        df = pd.read_csv(currentFile, sep=separator, parse_dates=False, skiprows=HeaderPos)
    else:
        df = pd.read_fwf(currentFile, parse_dates=False, header=HeaderPos, widths=width)
        if debug: print('Opening File as Fixed Width')
    dupCols = getDuplicateColumns(df)

    df  = df.drop(columns=dupCols)
    fieldStructure = pd.DataFrame(index=[df.columns], columns=['Target Name','Source Name','Column Position','Column Width','DataType','Size','Format', 'KEY','Default','Comments','Unique', 'ImpactsGrain', 'HasNULLs'])
    totalRowCount = df.shape[0]
    totalDupRows = df[df.duplicated()].shape[0]
    if totalDupRows > 0:
        print('!!!!!!!!!WARNING!!!!!!!! This file contains ' + str(totalDupRows) + ' duplicate rows!')
    if len(dupCols)> 0:
        fieldStructure.loc['Duplicate','Target Name'] = 'DUPLICATE Fields:' + '-'.join(dupCols)
        print('!!!!!!!!!WARNING!!!!!!!! The following columns were identified as a duplicate column and will be removed from the final mapping')
        if debug: print(dupCols)
    if debug: print('Columns in the Dataset',df.columns)
    if debug: print(fieldStructure)   
    counter = 1
    for fieldName in df.columns:
        print('Processing Field: ' + fieldName)
        fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Source Name'] = fieldName
        fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Target Name'] = fieldName
        fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Column Position'] = counter
        if separator =='FWF':fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Column Width'] = width[counter-1]
        counter +=1
        fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'DataType'] = str(df[fieldName].dtypes).replace('64', '',1)
        if str(df[fieldName].dtypes).replace('64', '',1) == 'float':
            if df[fieldName].fillna(1).apply(float.is_integer).all():
                fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'DataType'] = 'int'
            else:
                fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'DataType'] = 'float'
        format = ''
        dateFlg = True
        if df[fieldName].isnull().all(): fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'DataType'] = 'Unknown'
        if df[fieldName].dtypes == 'object':
            fieldValue = str(df.loc[df.loc[:,fieldName].first_valid_index(),fieldName])
            if debug: print('First non NaN Index & Value: ',str(df.loc[:,fieldName].first_valid_index()), str(fieldValue))
            try:
                dateTime = parse(fieldValue,fuzzy=False)
            except ValueError:
                dateFlg = False
            if dateFlg == True:
                shortMonth = False
                shortDate = False
                if debug: print('Input Date:', fieldValue)
                if debug: print('Interpreted Date',dateTime)

                yrSt = fieldValue.find(str(dateTime.year))
                if debug: print('Year Start Position: ',yrSt)
                format = fieldValue.replace(str(dateTime.year), 'yyyy',1)
                if yrSt == -1:
                    format = fieldValue.replace(str(dateTime.year)[2:], 'yy',1)
                if debug: print('Year format: ',format)

                noMonth=False
                monSt = format.find(str(dateTime.month).zfill(2))
                if debug: print('2 Digit Month Position:',monSt)
                format = format.replace(str(dateTime.month).zfill(2), 'mm',1)
                if monSt == -1:
                    monSt1 = format.find(str(dateTime.month))
                    if monSt1 != -1:
                        shortMonth = True
                        format = format.replace(str(dateTime.month).zfill(1), 'mm',1)
                    else:
                        noMonth = True
                #Check if Month Name or Abbreviations are used
                if noMonth:
                    abbr=map(str.upper,calendar.month_abbr[1:])
                    fmnth=map(str.upper,calendar.month_name[1:])
                    if debug: print(abbr)
                    for mon in abbr:
                        if(mon in format.upper()):
                            if debug: print('Month Abbr used in this date format', mon)
                            noMonth = False
                            format = format.replace(mon, 'MMM',1)
                    for mon in fmnth:
                        if(mon in format.upper()):
                            if debug: print('Month Name used in this date format', mon)
                            noMonth = False
                            format = format.replace(mon, 'MMMM',1)
                if debug: print('Month Format: ',format)

                daySt = format.find(str(dateTime.day).zfill(2))
                if debug: print('2 Digit Day Position: ',daySt)
                format = format.replace(str(dateTime.day).zfill(2), 'dd',1)
                if daySt == -1:
                    daySt1 = format.find(str(dateTime.day))
                    if daySt1 != -1 and not noMonth:
                        shortDate = True
                        format = format.replace(str(dateTime.day), 'dd',1)
                if debug: print('Day format: ',format)

                hhSt = format.find(str(dateTime.hour).zfill(2))
                if debug: print('2 digit Hour Position: ',hhSt)
                format = format.replace(str(dateTime.hour).zfill(2), 'HH',1)
                if debug: print('2 digit Hour Format: ',format)
                if hhSt == -1:
                    hhSt = format.find(str(dateTime.hour).zfill(2))
                    if debug: print('24 Hour Format Position: ',hhSt)
                    format = format.replace(str(dateTime.hour).zfill(2), 'HH',1)
                    if debug: print('24 Hour Format: ',format)
                if hhSt == -1:
                    hhSt = format.find(str(dateTime.hour))
                    if debug: print('1 digit Hour Position: ',hhSt)
                    format = format.replace(str(dateTime.hour), 'H',1)

                mnSt = format.find(str(dateTime.minute).zfill(2))
                if debug: print('Mins Position:',mnSt)
                format = format.replace(str(dateTime.minute).zfill(2), 'MM',1)
                if debug: print('Mins Format: ',format)

                secSt = format.find(str(dateTime.second).zfill(2))
                if debug: print('Seconds Position',secSt)
                format = format.replace(str(dateTime.second).zfill(2), 'SS',1)
                if debug: print('Seconds Format',format)

                if shortMonth or shortDate:
                    format = format + ';' + format.replace(str('mm'), 'm',1).replace(str('dd'), 'd',1)
                    if debug: print('Date Format Identified as :', format)
                fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'DataType'] = 'Timestamp'
            else:
                fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'DataType'] = 'String'
        if df[fieldName].isnull().all():    
            fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Size'] = 0
        else:
            fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Size'] = df[fieldName].map(str).apply(len).max()
        fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Format'] = format
        fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Unique'] = df[fieldName].is_unique
        dftmp = df.drop(columns=fieldName)
        # if debug: print(dftmp.head())
        dupRows = dftmp[dftmp.duplicated()].shape[0]
        if dupRows > totalDupRows:
            grainFlg = True
        else:
            grainFlg = False
        fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'ImpactsGrain'] = grainFlg    # NEEDS MORE ANALYSIS
        if df[fieldName].isna().sum() > 0:
            fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'HasNULLs'] = True
        else:
            fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'HasNULLs'] = False

    if debug: print(df.columns)
    if debug: print(fieldStructure)
    return fieldStructure


# Merge all File Mappings to master mapping file.
def addToMaster(fieldStructure):
    if debug: print('Consolidating Multiple Mappings.....')
    #if debug: print(fieldStructure.loc[:,'Target Name'])
    #masterFields
    #masterFields.loc[:,'Format']='XXX'
    masterFields['Format'] = masterFields.Format.apply(lambda x: x if not (pd.isnull(x) or x=='') else 'XXX')
    if debug: print(masterFields['Format'])
    for index, row in fieldStructure.iterrows():
        #if debug: print(row)
        masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Target Name']=row['Target Name']
        masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Source Name']=row['Source Name']
        if pd.isnull(masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Column Position']):
            masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Column Position']=row['Column Position']
        else:        
            if masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Column Position']!=row['Column Position']:
                if debug: print(bcolors.WARNING + "WARNING: Column positions vary by file."+ bcolors.ENDC)
        if pd.isnull(masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Column Width']):
            masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Column Width']=row['Column Width']
        else:
            if masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Column Width']<row['Column Width']:
                if debug: print('!!!!!!!!!WARNING!!!!!!!! Column Widths vary by file.Merge may not be accurate')
                masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Column Width']=row['Column Width']
        if pd.isnull(masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'DataType']):
            masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'DataType']=row['DataType']
        else:
            if masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'DataType']!=row['DataType']:
                if row['DataType']== 'float': masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'DataType'] = float
                if row['DataType']=='Timestamp': masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'DataType'] = Timestamp
        if pd.isnull(masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Size']):
            masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Size']=row['Size']
        else:
            if masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Size']<row['Size']:
                masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Size']=row['Size']
        if pd.isnull(masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Format']):masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Format']='XXX'
        if not(pd.isnull(row['Format']) or row['Format']==''):
            if debug: print('Checking if ',row['Format'], ' not in ', masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Format'])
            if debug: print('Size of Format value is:', str(len(row['Format'])))
            if debug: print('Check to see if the value is NULL: ', pd.isnull(row['Format']))
            if row['Format'] not in masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Format']:                
                masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Format'] +=  row['Format']
                masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Format'] +=  ';'
        if pd.isnull(masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Unique']):
            masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Unique'] = row['Unique']
        else:
            if not(row['Unique']): masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'Unique'] = False
        if pd.isnull(masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'ImpactsGrain']):
            masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'ImpactsGrain'] = row['ImpactsGrain']
        else:
            if row['ImpactsGrain']: masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'ImpactsGrain'] = True
        if pd.isnull(masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'HasNULLs']):
            masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'HasNULLs'] = row['HasNULLs']
        else:
            if row['HasNULLs']: masterFields.loc[row['Target Name'],'HasNULLs'] = True

    if debug: print(masterFields)


def printMapping(fileNameParts,separator,HeaderPos,fieldStructure):
    fileNameParts[len(fileNameParts) -1] = 'map'
    name='.'.join(fileNameParts)
    name+='.csv'
    if debug: print(name)
    currentFile = open(path +"\\" +name, "w+")
    currentFile.write('Source file directory,' + path + '\n')
    currentFile.write('Source file pattern,' + 'TBD' + '\n')
    currentFile.write('Target table name,' + '[ENTER TABLENAME]' + '\n')
    if separator != ' ':
        currentFile.write('Field Seperator,"' + separator + '"\n')
    else:
        currentFile.write('Field Seperator,"' + 'FWF' + '"\n')
    currentFile.write('Skip Rows,' + str(HeaderPos) + '\n' + '\n')
    currentFile.close()
    fieldStructure.to_csv(path +"\\" +name, mode='a', index= False, header= True )




# Read all files in directory
files = os.listdir(path)
masterSep='INIT'
textFormats = ["txt","csv","log"]
#Print all files in directory
for name in files:
    print('>>>>>>  CURRENTLY PROCESSING FILE : ',name)
    fileNameParts = str.split(name, ".")
    if debug: print(fileNameParts)
    width=[0]
    if '.map.' in name:
        print('Skip current file (Output File): ',name)
        continue
    if fileNameParts[len(fileNameParts) -1] in textFormats:
        if debug: print("This is a text file.")
        separator, HeaderPos = identifySeparator(name)
        if separator != '-1':
            print('Seperator successfully identified as: ' + separator)
        else:
            print('Unable to identify Separator. This file will be skipped!')
            continue
        if separator == ' ':
            print('This file may be a fixed width file')
            HeaderPos, width=identifyFixedWidth(name)
            if debug: print('Width Array ',width, len(width))
            if len(width)<=1:
                print('This file may be space seperated however it is not a fixed width file.')
                continue
            else:
                separator = 'FWF'
        fieldStructure = identifyFields(name, separator, HeaderPos, width)
        if masterSep !='INIT':
            if (masterSep != separator) and consolidate:
                print('These files have different seperators so results will not be consolidated')
                consolidate=False
        else:
            masterSep = separator
        print('Field Structure identified successfully')
        # Print Mapping Sheet
        # if debug: print(fieldStructure)
        if consolidate: addToMaster(fieldStructure)
        printMapping(fileNameParts,separator,HeaderPos,fieldStructure)
    else:
        print('Skip current file (Unknown Format) : ',name)
#Prepare to print consolidated results
if consolidate:
    fileNameParts[0] = 'FinalMappingSheet'
    masterFields['Format'] = [x[3:] for x in masterFields['Format']]

    printMapping(fileNameParts,separator,HeaderPos,masterFields)
```

Comment: I'd be very interested to see a pythonic refactoring of the debug statements

Comment: Can you include the example input as text instead of an image? This way reviewers don't need to type out your whole file...

Comment: Add the example input as text.

Comment: Can someone let me know if there is a better way to get the date format string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be relatively long, but I don't have a TL;DR section

## `if debug: print`

Whenever you see code repeated like this, it's quite often you can refactor it into either a function, or there's a builtin to support it. Fortunately, the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) module makes this quite simple. You do lose a bit of speed over the `if` statement, but it's a much easier call to read and visually separate from the rest of your code:

```py
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# I'm specifying sys.stdout because default is sys.stderr which
# may or may not be viewable in your console, whereas sys.stdout
# is always viewable
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))

for i in range(10):
    if i > 8:
       logger.debug(f'{i}')
       # do other things

9

# rather than
for i in range(10):
    if i > 8:
        if debug:
            print(i)
        # do other things

9
```

You can set this up with a `level` mapping to point to other logging levels:

```py
levels = {True: logging.DEBUG,
          False: logging.INFO}

debug = True

logger.setLevel(levels[debug])
```

This way you don't lose your original way of keeping track of your debug status. The major benefit is that it doesn't visually collide with the rest of your flow control. When you have a ton of `if` statements, visually sifting through to ignore `if debug` becomes a major pain.

The way to fix this is to find `if debug print` and replace it with `logger.debug`, and everywhere else `print` is needs to be `logger.info`, `logger.warn`, or `logger.exception` (which will include a stack trace for you :) ). You'll need to fix the print arguments as well, how to do that is below.

### Using `logger` with objects

I'd probably start switching to using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python), this way you avoid string concatenation and your code is a bit more readable:

```py
import pandas as pd
import logging
import sys

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns = list('abc'))

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))


logger.debug(f'My dataframe is \n{df.head()}')
My dataframe is
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

# you can still use it for objects by themselves
logger.debug(df.head())
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

# To show logging.exception behavior
def f():
  raise TypeError("Some random error")

try:
  f()
except TypeError as e:
  logger.exception("An error occurred")

An error occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
TypeError: Some random error
```

## Opening and closing files

I see lots of different ways you open files:

```py
for line in open(file):
   ...

fh = open(file)
for line in fh:
   ...
```

It's best to be consistent, and the most pythonic way to [open a file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is to use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with):

```py
with open(file) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        ...
```

This removes the need to manually close the file, since even on an exception, the handle is closed and you don't have to wait for `fh` to exit function scope.

## os.listdir vs os.scandir

If your directories are particularly large, it can be quite advantageous to use `os.scandir` since it produces a generator rather than a list:

```py
os.listdir('.')
['newfile.py', '.Rhistory', 'VMBash.txt', '.config', 'Music', '.sparkmagic', 'transcripts.tar.gz', '.amlinstaller', 'spotify.docx', 'tree.py', '.condarc', '.docker', 'company.20190102.idx.1', 'itertools_loop.py', 'sql2019.ipynb', 'somexml.xml', 'temp'...]

os.scandir('.')
<posix.ScandirIterator object at 0x10bbb51b0>
```

For large directories, you'd have to wait for `listdir` to aggregate all of the files into memory, which could be either a) long-running or b) crash your machine (probably not but who knows). You would iterate over `scandir` with the `file.name` attribute to get back to what you had before:

```py
for file in os.scandir('.'):
    print(file.name)

newfile.py
.Rhistory
VMBash.txt
...
```

## Tracking an Index

If you ever find yourself doing the following:

```py
counter = 0

for x in iterable:
  something[x] = 1
  counter += 1
```

It's probably better to use `enumerate` to track the index:

```py
l = list('abcd')

for idx, item in enumerate(l):
  print(idx)

0
1
2
3
```

You can also provide a `start` kwarg to tell `enumerate` where to begin:

```py
l = list('abcd')

for idx, item in enumerate(l, start=1):
  print(idx)

1
2
3
4
```

So in your `identifyFields` function, I would definitely leverage that:

```py
for counter, field_name in enumerate(df.columns, start=1):
  # rest of loop
```

## Counter

When you are iterating over your file to get character counts, you are losing speed with extra steps by converting to `list`, then checking for `\n`, then building your Counter. `Counter` will consume a string, and `\n` is a single string object. Move that into a separate function for separation of concerns:

```py
def read_file(filepath):
    # It is much better practice to open files using the with context manager
    # it's safer and less error-prone
    with open(filepath) as fh:
        char_counts = []

        for line in fh:
            # don't construct a list, there's no need,
            # just check if startswith, which is the same
            # as line[0] == '\n'
            if not line.startswith('\n'):
                # Counter will consume a string
                char_counts.append(Counter(line))
    return char_counts

char_counts = read_file(name)
```

Or, a bit more succinctly as a list comprehension:

```py
def read_file(name):
    with open(filename) as fh:
        return [Counter(line) for line in fh if not line.startswith('\n')]
```

Where the `str.startwith` is a bit more robust for variable-length strings, as it avoids the `if mystring[:len(to_check)] == to_check` mess.

## Checking duplicate columns

It might be easier to leverage `itertools.combinations` to get pairs of columns in your dataframe, then use the `pd.Series.all()` function to check the values:

```py
# change your naming to fit with common naming standards for
# variables and functions, pep linked below
def get_duplicate_columns(df):
    '''
    You are looking for non-repeated combinations of columns, so use
    itertools.combinations to accomplish this, it's more efficient and
    easier to see what you are trying to do, rather than tracking an index
    '''
    duplicate_column_names = set()
    # Iterate over all pairs of columns in df
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
        # will check if every entry in the series is True
        if (df[a] == df[b]).all():
            duplicate_column_names.add(b)

    return list(duplicate_column_names)
```

This way you avoid the nested loops, and you are just checking across the boolean mask.

## Check pandas datatype for column

It is both unclear and bad practice to do:

```py
if str(df[fieldName].dtypes).replace('64', '',1) == 'float':
```

To explicitly check a pandas datatype, use the `dtype` on a `pd.Series` by accessing the column directly:

```py
import numpy as np

if df[field_name].dtype == np.float64:
  # do things
```

You'll need `numpy` because the dtypes for pandas inherit from `numpy` dtypes. An even clearer way to check (in case you get `np.float32` instead of `np.float64`, for example) is to leverage the `pandas.api.types`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas.api.types as pdtypes

if pdtypes.is_float_dtype(df[field_name]):
  # do things
```

This might be the preferred way to go, since you are assuming that you will always get `float64`, where you might not. This also works for other types:

```py
if pdtypes.is_integer_dtype(df[field_name]):
  pass

elif pdtypes.is_object_dtype(df[field_name]):
  pass

elif pdtypes.is_datetimetz(df[field_name]):
  pass

# etc
```

## Checking last element in an indexed data structure

Instead of using `object[len(object) - 1]`, just use `object[-1]`. Negative indexing also works for counting backwards:

```py
x = list('abcdefg')

# get the last element
x[-1]
'g'

# get the third-to-last element
x[-3]
'e'
```

## Finding a substring using str.find

In your datetime processing logic there's a ton of the following:

```py
year_st = field_value.find(str(date_time.year))

if year_st == -1:
  # do something
```

This will never evaluate to true, because `find` will never return a negative index:

```py
mystr = 'abcd'

mystr.find('d')
# 3
```

Likewise, later you use:

```py
mon_st = format.find(str(dateTime.month))
if mon_st != -1:
  # do things
```

This will always evaluate to `True`.

This falls under checking `str.endswith`, since you want to know if that block of text is the last element in the string:

```py
if field_value.endswith(str(date_time.year)):
  # do things
```

## tuples vs lists

There are numerous places in your code where you use lists that you do not modify:

```py
if ending not in formats:

...
df = df.drop(columns=skipSeperator, errors='ignore')

...
```

You incur extra overhead by allocating a mutable data structure:

```py
import sys

lst, tup = list(range(100)), tuple(range(100))

sys.getsizeof(lst)
1008

sys.getsizeof(tup)
848
```

With this in mind, it's better to stick with the smaller data structure.

## Pandas Recommendations

### data-type checking

This kind of code-snippet is not something you'll want:

```py
if str(df[fieldName].dtypes).replace('64', '',1) == 'float':
```

You're calling `dtypes`, then coercing it to a string, then replacing it, *then* comparing to a fixed string. No need, those are numpy datatypes, so just do:

```py
if df[fieldName].dtype == np.float64:
```

### str functions

You can refactor code snippets like:

```py
fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Size'] = df[fieldName].map(str).apply(len).max()
```

To be

```py
fieldStructure.loc[fieldName, 'Size'] = df[fieldName].str.len().max()
```

Since the field is already a string type, you shouldn't need to map everything with `str`, and then the `len` operation should already be supported. The latter is faster largely because of the fewer operations that need to occur:

#### timing

```py
python -m timeit -s "import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame([['kladflna', 'l;adfkadf', ';aljdnvohauehfkadflan'] for i in range(1000)], columns=list(range(3)))" 'df[2].map(str).apply(len).max()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 506 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame([['kladflna', 'l;adfkadf', ';aljdnvohauehfkadflan'] for i in range(1000)], columns=list(range(3)))" 'df[2].str.len().max()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 351 usec per loop
```

#### function calls

```py
from dis import dis

import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame([['kladflna', 'l;adfkadf', ';aljdnvohauehfkadflan'] for i in range(1000)], columns=list(range(3)))

def f(df):
    df[2].map(str).apply(len).max()

def g(df):
    df[2].str.len().max()

dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (df)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_SUBSCR
              6 LOAD_ATTR                0 (map)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (str)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 LOAD_ATTR                2 (apply)
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (len)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 LOAD_ATTR                4 (max)
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             22 POP_TOP
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE

dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (df)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_SUBSCR
              6 LOAD_ATTR                0 (str)
              8 LOAD_ATTR                1 (len)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 LOAD_ATTR                2 (max)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             16 POP_TOP
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

## Opening a file multiple times

In your `identifyFixedWidth` function, you open and read a file multiple times. I would say this makes it a candidate for a refactor, since these tasks should probably be broken into smaller functions:

```py
def identify_fixed_width(name):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, name)

    # open the file here, and re-use the file-handle with fh.seek(0)
    with open(filepath) as fh:
        number_lines, avg_chars, max_length = get_avg_chars(fh)

        # re-use this file handle, go back to the beginning
        fh.seek(0)
        counter = find_header(fh, avg_chars)

        fh.seek(0)
        col_pos = get_row_counter(fh, counter)

    common = list(set.intersection(*map(set, col_pos))
    logger.debug(f"Potential field separator posistions: {common}")

    # replace this with a list comprehension, it's faster and more compact
    new_common = [x for x in common if (x-1) not in common]
    new_common.append(max_len)

    logger.debug(f"Field separator positions identified as {new_common}"

    # do not shadow builtin names like range. If you must, use a leading underscore
    _range = len(new_common)
    width = []

    # underscore will show an unused or throwaway variable
    for i, _ in enumerate(new_common[0:_range-1]):
        width.append(new_common[i+1] - new_common[i])

    logger.debug(f'Column Lengths: {width}') 
    return counter, width  


def get_avg_chars(fh):
    """
    Use enumerate to track the index here and
    just count how much you want to decrement from the index
    at the end
    """
    decrement, max_len, total_chars = 0, 0, 0

    for idx, line in enumerate(fh, start=1)
        total_chars += len(line)
        if len(line) <= 2:
            decrement += 1

        # this can be evaluated with a ternary expression
        max_len = len(line) if len(line) > max_len else max_len

    # at the end of the for loop, idx is the length of the file
    num_lines = idx - decrement
    avg_chars = total_chars / num_lines

    return num_lines, avg_chars, max_len


def find_header(fh, avg_chars):
    counter = 0
    for line in fh:
        logger.debug(f"{counter} has {len(line)} chars")
        lower = len(line) <= avg_chars * 0.9
        upper = len(line) >= avg_chars * 1.1
        if upper or lower:
            logger.debug(f"Line {counter}: Maybe part of header and needs to be skipped")
            counter += 1
        else:
            logger.debug(f"Header found at {counter}")   
            break
    return counter


def get_row_counter(fh, counter):
    """
    Again, use enumerate here for row_counter
    """ 
    col_pos = []
    for row_counter, line in enumerate(fh):
        if row_counter <= counter:
             continue
        blanks = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(' ', line)]
        if len(blanks) > 2:
            # you've already declared this variable, so use it 
            col_pos.append(blanks)
            if row_counter <= 5:
                logger.debug(col_pos[-1])
    return col_pos
```

Now, it's easier to break apart, debug, and separate out pieces of work within a function.

## Style

A few things

1. Variable and function names [should be lowercase](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) with words separated by underscores (`_`). Upper case is usually reserved for types, classes, etc. So something like `rowCounter` should really be `row_counter`.
2. When checking for [equivalence with singletons such as `None`, `True`, and `False`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), it is usually better to use `if value:` or `if not value`:

```py
# change this to
if date_flag == True:

# this
if date_flag:
```

3. I'm not sure if there's a PEP for it, but visually separating blocks of code with newlines can be very helpful. As an example:

```py
    logger.debug('% of rows missing the charecter')
    logger.debug(df.isna().sum()/ df.isna().count())
    cleanupCandidates=df.dropna(axis='columns', thresh = (df.shape[0] + 1)*.8).fillna(-1)
    logger.debug('Dropping characters not present in 80% of the columns')
    logger.debug(cleanupCandidates.head())
    lowestVariance = 0
    spaceDetectedFlag = False
    Separator2 = ''
    for character in cleanupCandidates.columns:
        logger.debug('**********' + character +' **********')
        x = cleanupCandidates.loc[:,character].var()
        logger.debug('Calculated variance : ' + str(x) )
        if character == ' ':
            spaceDetectedFlag = True
            logger.debug('Potential position based file...')
            continue
        if lowestVariance >= x:
            lowestVariance =x
            Separator2 = character
        logger.debug("Separator identified as : " + Separator2 + ' using METHOD 2')
    if Separator == Separator2:
        commonSep= Separator
    else:
        commonSep = list(set(Candidates).intersection(cleanupCandidates.columns))
        logger.debug('Both methods identify '+ str(commonSep) + 'as one of the separator candidates.')
        maxMode = 0
        modeTable = cleanupCandidates.mode()
```

This just looks like a gigantic wall of code, and is difficult to quickly scan for keywords, patterns, etc. Try breaking up the code by breaking things into logical steps:

```py
# Break all of this apart
    logger.debug('% of rows missing the charecter')
    logger.debug(df.isna().sum()/ df.isna().count())

    cleanupCandidates=df.dropna(axis='columns', thresh = (df.shape[0] + 1)*.8).fillna(-1)
    logger.debug('Dropping characters not present in 80% of the columns')
    logger.debug(cleanupCandidates.head())

    lowestVariance = 0
    spaceDetectedFlag = False
    Separator2 = ''

    for character in cleanupCandidates.columns:
        logger.debug('**********' + character +' **********')
        x = cleanupCandidates.loc[:,character].var()
        logger.debug('Calculated variance : ' + str(x) )

        # separate these if statements, they do different things
        if character == ' ':
            spaceDetectedFlag = True
            logger.debug('Potential position based file...')
            continue

        if lowestVariance >= x:
            lowestVariance =x
            Separator2 = character

        logger.debug("Separator identified as : " + Separator2 + ' using METHOD 2')

    # if, elif, else should be connected because they are one logical
    # block of code
    if Separator == Separator2:
        commonSep= Separator
    else:
        commonSep = list(set(Candidates).intersection(cleanupCandidates.columns))
        logger.debug('Both methods identify '+ str(commonSep) + 'as one of the separator candidates.')
        maxMode = 0
        modeTable = cleanupCandidates.mode()
```

4. Make sure there's [consistent whitespace around variables and operators.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations)

```py
# go from this
lowest_variance =x
common_sep= separator
# to this
lowest_variance = x
common_sep = separator
```